# Is there a way to delete main form data if data in subform is empty?

Tags: forms, ms-access, subform, ms-access-forms

I have a form in MS Access that has a subform.

My problem is that if the user starts filling the main form with `date`, `customer`, `IDOrderNumber` etc. and suddenly wants to leave the form without entering data in the subform, when he tries to find that form with the same `IDOrderNumber`, he can't. But when he enters the same `IDOrderNumber` he can't because it's the primary key and can't allow duplicate values.

What should I do?

I tried to add a search field for `IDOrderNumber` but it doesn't work - it shows empty Master and Child form/subform. Also I have an Order list Form and I can't access a form that has no subform data entered..

I need a solution because it is a big problem for my customer/user of database.

Thanks all in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The way it sounds to me, is that you want the record in the main form to be deleted if no data is entered in the subform. Ill assume the data in the subform is bound to a different table, and used for multiple records tied to IDOrderNumber

I would suggestion using the below vba code. I'm assuming some of your database's structure, so correct me as needed

This code will go in your MainForms `Form_Close()` Event

```
Private Sub Form_Close()

Dim recordexists as Integer
Dim db as Database
Dim rs as Recordset
Dim strSQL as String


strSQL = "SELECT * FROM YourSecondaryTable T2 WHERE T2.IDOrderNumber =" & Me.IDOrderNumberField.Value
Set db = CurrentDb()
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

'This recordset is checking to see if a value in the secondary table exists with the OrderNumber that exists in the main table.
With rs
    If Not .BOF And Not .EOF Then
        .MoveFirst
        While (Not .EOF)
            'If the code gets to this point, then a record exists in your subform.
            'So we set the value to 1
            recordexists = 1  
        Wend
    End If
    .Close
End With

'If the above recordset didnt find anything, the the recordexists value would never be set.
'Therefore you want to delete the parent record. So we delete it
If recordexists = 0 Then

    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE TOP 1 FROM YourMainTable T1 WHERE T1.IDOrderNumber = " & Me.IDOrderNumberField.Value
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True


End IF

Set rs = Nothing
Set db = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: What "went wrong" when you tried it? not sure how to assist further. Did you receive an error? What happened?

Comment: Sry i replied below my 1st comment, here is picture of code https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEmXv.jpg
 Something went wrong, mby i didn't understand You well. You guessed all right about my structure - Main form that make Table1 as "Porudzbina" (Primary Key "IDPorudžbine") and in subform T2 as "PorudzbinaRoba" ("IDPorudžbine")

Comment: I need the error you are receiving. I see what line is failing, but i need to know why its failing

Comment: Thanks @Pants but i finally found a solution, it took me whole day.
Private Sub Izaði_Click()
With [PorudzbinaRoba Query subform].Form
If .Recordset.RecordCount = 0 Then
DoCmd.RunCommand (acCmdDeleteRecord)
DoCmd.Close
Else
DoCmd.Close
End If
End With
End Sub
Thanks for your effort, i used your code to understand something, You helped a lot!!!

Comment: I would recommend writing this solution as an answer to your own question, then accepting that as the solution. This may help others in the future. Glad i could be of some help